# Pentaho - How to run the job as stream

Tags: rabbitmq, pentaho, etl, publish-subscribe, producer-consumer

I am new to **Pentaho**. I have a requirement that i need to create a ETL job to read the message from **rabbitMQ** and transform it and store it in a db. I have created the ETL using IC AMQP plugin. But i couldn't find a way to run the job as stream. The Job Scheduler has options **Repeat** and **No Interval**, but enabling this option produces performance issue. I am looking for a solution to run the Job as stream and when a message is queued the consumer should able to retrieve the queued message and process it. Can anyone help me on this? I am using PDI version 8.1.0.0-365.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use crontab!

The Job Scheduler is in competition with the Pentaho EE, so they did not invest much in it.

And the community prefers a crontab, so we did not invest much in it neither.